# How do I make Visual Studio Community 2017 know that I already have .NET Core 2.1.500 installed on my machine?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

A few days ago, I update .NET Core on my machine to the latest stable version version `2.1.500`.

So, now I have the following versions of .NET Core co-exist on my machine.

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk>dir /b
1.0.0
1.0.0-preview2-003131
2.1.500
```

However, when I create a new **Console Application (.NET Core)** in Visual Studio Community 2017, and go to the **Property Pages** for the project, I do not see an entry for the version `2.1.500` of .NET Core.

[image]

I am guessing Visual Studio has a separate copy of .NET Core that it privately holds? Just like it holds its own copy of MS Build? If that's the case, that is a problem because every time I update my .NET Core version, I will need to do something extra to make Visual Studio know about it?

How do I make Visual Studio know that I've got other versions?

Comment: Which exact version of VS 2017 are you running (E.g. it's `15.<something>`, what's the something)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It reads VisualStudio/15.0.0-RTW+2.6228.4.

Comment: Install updates then. 15.3 was required for 2.0, 15.6 for 2.1, so far as I recall

Comment: For stuff to appear in that DropDown - you need to install Targeting Pack (like for Core 2.1 in your case). But I dont seem to find one on Microsoft site.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever and Prateek, thank you both. I am trying out an update. Will post back.